# MutableLiveData is stacked at initial value

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm quite new in Kotlin but try to write a Kotlin code with 3 screen fragments managed by a NavController:

```
                    navController.navigate(it) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                            inclusive = false
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true

....

            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = BottomAppBarPage.Home.route,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                composable(BottomAppBarPage.Home.route) {
                    HomePage(name)
                }

                composable(BottomAppBarPage.Charts.route) {
                    ChartsPage(name)
                }

                composable(BottomAppBarPage.Table.route) {
                    TablePage(name)
                }

            }
```

When I start the app HomePage loads the values using the ViewModel as expected, but if I click on Charts o Table and go back to the HomePage, the values are kept with the initial MutableLiveData value.

The values are loaded with LaunchedEffect:

```
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        viewModel.getData(context, name, currentInstance)
    }
```

The ViewModel code:

```
    private val _refDate = MutableLiveData("")
    val refDate: LiveData<String> = _refDate

    suspend fun getData(context: Context, name: String, date: Calendar) {
        val balanceTemp = BalanceDb.getDatabase(context).balanceDao().getByName(name)
        _refDate.value = balanceTemp.RefDate
        }
    }
```

Activity code:

```
    val refDate: String by viewModel.refDate.observeAsState("")
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Thank you all!

I have another similar activity and the code is working well. I added a Log inside getData and the values is read and _refDate.value is updated but for some reason it's not reflected on the UI.